# How can I find webform e-mail submission values keys?

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

I created a Webform and now I want to send an email on submit to the customer. But I'm not understanding how to take the submission values one by one and use it in the email body.

The submission tokens description says:

> %value[key] - A value without additional formatting. Elements may be
>   accessed such as %value[fieldset_a][key_b]. Do not include quotes.

What kind of key the `%value` array have got? How can I find they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer.

Lets say I've 4 fields in Webform

`Label`    -   `Field Key`

```
First Name - first_name

Last Name - last_name

Phone Number - phone_number

Message - message
```

Here is the way to access them in *template* field

For example if you want to display name as the combination of *First Name and Last Name*

```
Name:  %value[first_name] %value[last_name]
```

Then this appears in mail like

```
Name: Krishna Mohan
```

If you want to access a individual *field value with Label*

For example Phone number

```
%email[phone_number]
```

This appears in mail like

```
Phone Number - 555-555-5225
```

I've tested this and works great! Hope this helps